# Unusual traffic detected in Google Analytics for Android App immediately after internal test release

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-analytics, react-native-firebase

I am new to Google Analytics.

I added Google Analytics to my hybrid app built with react native. I used "@react-native-firebase" to implement GA into my app.

When I added my app to internal testing release on "Google Play Store Console", immediately after some time there were more than 30 plus users showed up on Google Analytics console. This is highly unlikely considering I didn't share the link. Also all these users were in United States with the event `first_open_time` using wide range of os version and device model.

So my suspicion is Google is internally testing my app before actually rolling out the application.

Has anyone else faced this or something similar to this before? If yes, is there any workaround on how to identify these fake triggers and not log them to Google Analytics? (I assumed that for the proper workflow with the GA these fake triggers would be hindrance, right?)